# Knockout if within attr binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, binding

I was wondering if something like this would be possible, or some neat workaround.

I've got an foreach loop around a form and want the for attribute to have

the following value:

1st form: `first_name`

2nd form: `first_name1`

3rd form: `first_name1`

etc
etc

```
<label data-bind="attr: {for: 'first_name' + ($index() + 1)}">
```

So i need to use something like this:

```
<label data-bind="attr: {for: 'first_name' + if(($index() != 0){($index() + 1)})}">
```

Obviously this isn't gonna work, so i was wondering if anyone has a clever way of achieving this.

Comment: why not add a `pureComputed`? not do much in `data-bind`

Comment: 'first_name' + ($index() != 0 ? (''+($index() + 1)) : '') But looks like a candidate for model computed property.

Comment: Ah the shorthand works! Should've taught of that, if you post it as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: I've posted the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JavaScript ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
'first_name' + ($index() != 0 ? (''+($index() + 1)) : '')
```